# Who can edit the "Help Center"?

Tags: support

Who can edit the [Help Center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help)?

I'd like to suggest some changes. My notion is to propose the changes here in Chemistry Meta then have the changes made in the help center if there is a consensus to do so.

Answer (score 8):

### Who can edit the Help Centre?

**Diamond moderators**

i.e. myself (as of the time of writing), can edit a grand total of *two* Help Centre pages, namely:

- [The front page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). It is possible to add an introductory section at the top, although currently there is none.
- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

See also: [What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259914/what-parts-of-the-help-center-can-site-moderators-edit)

**Stack Exchange, the company**

The rest of the Help Centre cannot be touched by us, and can only be changed by employees of Stack Exchange, presumably the Community Managers (CMs). Jon Ericson, a former CM has written about this: [Improved Help Center - site-specific pages and site-specific edits to all pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279879/312770).

In this post, Jon left open the possibility of getting a CM to edit the Help Centre (after community discussion), although I'm not sure if anybody in the five years since has tried to do it. For what it's worth, this subsequent post: [Can we mark some more Help Center articles as moderator-editable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323708/can-we-mark-some-more-help-center-articles-as-moderator-editable) didn't quite get anywhere.

---

### A suggestion

I think it is more hassle than it is worth to contact the CMs with proposed changes. These would (for good reason) probably have to go through a lot of vetting, and is more bureaucratic than I would like.

Furthermore, I'm personally skeptical of how many people read the Help Centre in great detail (see Jon's post above, too). It's frequently the case where those who need to read it don't read it, and those who read it don't need to read it.

If we want to create more guidance, an easier process seems to be to write this on Meta, tag it with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), and then add a link to it at the top of the Help Centre (where we *can* edit).

Comment: Yes, with the general detour of [meta-tag:faq-proposed]. (Which does need a little cleaning up, I guess.)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン indeed - I can see some of these from which the tag can simply be removed... also some of the older [meta-tag:faq] ones may need to be reworked or removed...