# There's a hole in the help center awaiting to be filled

Tags: discussion

I just noticed (for reasons you could guess, [hint](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/)) that there is an edit link in the help center where I did not expect one to be.

There is no content to see, so let's create some.

Here's the page: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help

Here's a screen grab (from mobile - I know - lame) where you can see the link (for me, as I'm currently a moderator on this site l:

[image: where stuff should go]

I have looked at other pages and seen this space empty in many. There's not much to draw from then.

I think it should be reasonably short.

Comment: (if I'm fast enough, I might add a proposal once I'm not in a handheld device.)

Comment: Related: [Who can edit the "Help Center"?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4897/103369)

Comment: I can’t help but chuckle because this question reminds me of the quip about the publication “that filled a necessary hole in the literature!”

Answer (score 1):

I tried something, but the formatting options are very limited (no mhchem) and the text came out in a tiny font. Maybe an image would work. Is this documented somewhere?

[image]